# how to get file descriptors of PTY inside of a child?

Tags: linux, terminal, tty, pty, async

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html

in the "UNIX 98 pseudoterminals" it is said that `ptsname` can be used (and then `open`), but this function accepts file descriptor. i tried to put 0 (STDIN) and 1 (STDOUT) in there, but it fails with "Inappropriate ioctl for device". im running my program from gnome-terminal

im not writing another `xterm` program. just want to have file descriptors for asynchronous (non-blocking) non-canonical low-level input and output.

Comment: You might want to read `man 4 pts` to get a fuller understanding of how ptys work and when you would use `ptsname`.    From inside a gnome-terminal you directly have access to "slave" filedescriptor and would use `ttyname()` instead.

Comment: the `ttyname` function worked - it returned me `/dev/pts/0` for both `0` and `1`..  so is it a unified input/output "slave" that i must `open` and work on? in windows you create two "handles" with `CreateFileA` feeding it with `CONIN$` and `CONOUT$` names.. oke, ill go on experimenting..

Comment: By convention, on Unix, 0 is STDIN (input), 1 is STDOUT (output), 2 is STDERR (error).  The terminal program (gnome-terminal) will set these up for you when it creates the shell, and the programs you run from the command line will inherit them.   If you run a program other ways (eg from the `cron` task scheduler) then these are set up differently; there's no terminal in this case.  It all depends on how the prgram is started as to where 0/1/2 point.

Comment: yes, those i know, i found this manual https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Low_002dLevel-Terminal-Interface.html

it also says that file descriptors can be opened but going by the link "Low-level Input/Output" that information cant be found..

Comment: you need to rethink your problem.  In Unix you normally don't need to know the terminal your application is connected to.  The OS handles it for  you, your app doesn't need to do anything.  You don't need to open /dev/pts/0.  At most if you _need_ a terminal your code calls `isatty()` and aborts if not; otherwise the OS does it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

oke, ill try to answer myself.

- one have to find a real `tty` device with `isatty` function feeding `0`,`1`,`2` standard descriptors.
- when the real/true tty is found, the `ttyname` function will give the path to the terminal device.
- opening it with `open` gives a file descriptor

although it is stated that `O_RDONLY` (or `O_WRONLY`, one of them but not both) and `O_NONBLOCK` flags impose a non-blocking behavior, the `read` function on my system (Debian 12) still blocks after the terminal device switched into raw mode (using `tcgetattr`, `cfmakeraw` and `tcsetattr` functions).

the asynchronous reading is achieved with the help of `ioctl` + `FIONREAD` that returns bytes pending/available for reading (also i tried `poll` function, it works but seem like an overhead to me)

im not sure how to achieve/test asynchronous writing for now.